# How to catch an error during an Objective-C method call that takes no NSError argument?

Tags: objective-c, error-handling

I understand that some methods in Objective-C take a pointer to an [`NSError`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/index.html) object to be populated in the case where an error occurs.

But how to trap for an error occurring in an Objective-C method that does *not* take any such error argument?

For example, the [`canOpenURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:) method:

```
BOOL canOpen = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url];
```

…prints on the console:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "bogus://example/" - error: "(null)"
```

This is *not* because of the iOS 9 restriction on calling [`canOpenURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:) requiring a declaration of custom URL schemes to be tested in the plist as [discussed in this blog post](http://interactivelogic.net/wp/2016/03/how-to-query-custom-url-schemes-in-ios-9-hint-its-different-now/). In this case I did indeed declare the scheme. If the scheme were not declared in the plist, the error message would be a sentence rather than the word `null` you see above.

So this mysterious error seen above is being reported when (a) the custom URL scheme has been declared in a `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` string array in the plist AND (b) there is no app on the physical device willing to handle that schema (schema is 'bogus' in this example).

The [`canOpenURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:) method takes no argument for a [`NSError`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/index.html) to be populated. So how can I trap for this error happening, and avoid having the class print messages into my console or log?

Comment: You get boolean back that indicates the status of the corresponding call. I don't think you can prevent system from printing anything to console, but why would you care anyway?

Comment: @Andy I care because the error message pollutes the log with irrelevant entries. And I care because the error message leaks information that I might not want disclosed for privacy or security concerns.